# SweetAlert: Missing title argument

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm using sweet alert and i've got the following error when the error function is called from sweet alert. It works fine when the operation from the php files is successful. How can solve this problem? Many thanks

```
SweetAlert: Missing "title" argument!
```

**This is my javascript code**

```
function DeletePost() {
    swal({
        title: "Sei Sicuro?",
        text: "Questa operazione non è reversibile ed eliminerà la comunicazione i commenti ad essa connessi dal database!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Si, elimina comunicazione!",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
        cancelButtonText: "No, non procedere!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "../delete_all.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                  // swal('Deleted!', response.message, response.status);
                    swal({

                      title: response.title, 
                      text: response.message, 
                      type: response.status

                    },

                    function(){ 

                      location.reload();

                    }

                  );

                },

                error: function(response) {

                  swal({

                      title: response.title,
                      text: response.message, 
                      type: response.status

                    });


                }



            }); 

        } else {
            swal("Annulato!", "Operazione annullata con successo!", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

**And this is my php file**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Prelevo l'id dell'amministratore e lo passo ad una variabile
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    if($delete_inbox  = mysqli_prepare($conn, "DELETE FROM user_inbox where user_inbox_user=? AND user_inbox_status = 'trash'")){ 

           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete_inbox, 'i', $userid);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($delete_inbox);
           mysqli_stmt_close($delete_inbox);

    // Passo messaggio di risposta se l'operazione è andata a buon fine
    $response['title']  = 'Messaggi eliminati!';
    $response['message'] = 'Tutti i messaggi sono stati eliminati con successo.';
    $response['status']  = 'success';

    }else{

    // Passo messaggio di risposta se l'operazione non è andata a buon fine
    $response['title']  = 'Si è verificato un errore!';
    $response['message'] = 'Non è stato possibile eliminare i messaggi. Per favore contatta amministratore di sistema';
    $response['status']  = 'error';

    }

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: Did you got it working ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to convert json's response to javascript object

So it should be all right

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "../delete_all.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
         // swal('Deleted!', response.message, response.status);

         response= JSON.parse(response);

         swal({
            title: response.title, 
                  ...
```

I added this line

```
  response= JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: Ciao, Gianfrancesco I've tried your solution and now chrome console is giving this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: try `console.log(response)`, and `console.log(response.responseText)`

Comment: shouldn't it be `response = JSON.parse(response.responseText);` ?

Comment: or try `document.body.innerHTML =  response.responseText`

Comment: William Valhakis, that you are saying, so it changes all the content of the page

Comment: If there is an PHP error, it good to read it this way, am I wrong ?

Comment: No, Is a SweetAlert error that is a javascript library.

Comment: No is much simpler when initializing the swal builder needs title field, the php returns it within a json. (The php works), he forgot to convert the json to a javascript object

Comment: You know how to use this stackoverflow chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145785/discussion-between-william-valhakis-and-gianfrancesco-aurecchia).

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
  title: response.title || 'TITLE IS NOT SET', 
  text: response.message || 'MESSAGE IS NOT SET', 
  type: response.status || 'STATUS IS NOT SET'
}, function() {

});
```

what about

```
swal({
  title: JSON.parse(response.respoonseText).title
  // ...
}, function() {

});
```

```
response = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
swal({
  title: response.title || 'TITLE IS NOT SET', 
  text: response.message || 'MESSAGE IS NOT SET', 
  type: response.status || 'STATUS IS NOT SET'
}, function() {

});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, they are set into the php file and i call them using json, it works fine when the operation is successful but not if there is an error. Sorry i don't understand your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your help, it think the problem was in the php file I've changed it and now it works fine, the reason why i wanted to test it is so i can validate and sanitize the variable before i do a query to the database and i wanted to show an error if the query can't be performed

This is my php file

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $user_id = 'prova';

    if (!filter_var($user_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        // Passo messaggio di risposta se l'operazione non è andata a buon fine
    $response['title']  = 'Si è verificato un errore!';
    $response['message'] = 'Non è stato possibile eliminare i messaggi. Per favore contatta amministratore di sistema';
    $response['status']  = 'error';

    echo json_encode($response);

    }else{

    // Prelevo l'id dell'amministratore e lo passo ad una variabile effettuaando un sanitize
    $user_id = filter_var($_SESSION['user_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $delete_inbox  = mysqli_prepare($conn, "DELETE FROM user_inbox where user_inbox_user=? AND user_inbox_status = 'trash'");

           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete_inbox, 'i', $userid);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($delete_inbox);
           mysqli_stmt_close($delete_inbox);

    // Passo messaggio di risposta se l'operazione è andata a buon fine
    $response['title']  = 'Messaggi eliminati!';
    $response['message'] = 'Tutti i messaggi sono stati eliminati con successo.';
    $response['status']  = 'success';

    echo json_encode($response);

    }
```

**To generate the error i've set $user_id as not integer**

It is now working fine without using 
title: JSON.parse(response.respoonseText).title
or
response= JSON.parse(response);